# `:is()` is not working for pseudo-elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

The below [`:is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) usages are not working for pseudo-elements, can someone explain?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-Hans">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/normalize.css" />
    <style>
      body {
        background: #000;
        color: #eee;
      }
      button::before {
        content: 'foo';
      }
      /*  not working */
      :is(button::before) {
        content: none;
      }
      /*  not working either */
      button:is(::before) {
        content: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Test</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Pseudo-elements cannot be represented by the matches-any pseudo-class; they are not valid within :is(). <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#matches)</sup>

Comment: Is there any explanation as to why? Shortening `:before, :after` selectors would be super helpful...

Comment: @Tigerrrrr `:is()` is not meant to shorten a selector, it adds a condition to the selector when selecting "elements" and a pseudo-element is not an element so it doesn't make sense to have it inside :is()

Comment: [MDN > "Simplifying list selectors using `:is()`"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is#simplifying_list_selectors)

Comment: @Tigerrrrr I invite you to read that link (it seems you didn't) and also the one in my answer to understand why pseudo element aren't allowed inside the `:is()` selector. You don't need to read that much because the answer is within the first sentence

Comment: The MDN link was in response to "`:is()` is not meant to shorten a selector" and nothing else.

Comment: @Tigerrrrr it also answer your question, so read it

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not part of the current spec, although is still unclear / unresolved.

In addition to Temani's quote from the current CSS Selectors Level 4 Editors Draft (2 July 2021) specification, the same specification referenced notes this as an unresolved issue in [3.6.3. Pseudo-classing Pseudo-elements](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#pseudo-element-states).

> ISSUE 3    Clarify that :not() and :is() can be used when containing above-mentioned pseudos.

Fingers crossed this is resolved in either a future draft or the final Specification.

I was going to post the same question with the following tests.

```css
:is(div, h1)::before {
  content: 'Before - ';
}
:is(div, h1)::after {
  content: ' - After';
}
div:is(::before, ::after),
h1:is(::before, ::after),
:is(div, h1):is(::before, ::after),
:is(div, h1):is(::before),
:is(div, h1):is(::after) {
  content: 'None of these selectors work in Chrome 91 nor in Firefox 91. The :is() pseudo-class doesn\'t work with pseudo element selectors - 16 July 2021 - August Boehm.';
}

/* Select the h1 text to see what works */
h1::selection {
  background: red; 
} 
h1:is(::selection) {
  background: green;
}

/* What is frustrating is that these work */
input:is(:hover, :focus) {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div>div</div>
<h1>h1</h1>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Input">
```

https://codepen.io/augustography/pen/OJmprzq

Comment: I don't think the issue you linked is related to the question. They are simply missing a part to clarfiy how some pseudo-classes can be used with :is() (like you discovered) but it's clearly mentionned that pseudo element are not valid inside `:is()` and this won't change because it doens't make sense to have them inside `:is()`. You cannot select and element if it's a pseudo element (no element can be a pseudo element). Only a pseudo element is a pseudo element

Comment: To clarify my answer to the question that was asking for an explanation as to why ":is() usages are not working for pseudo-elements" is because "it's not part of the current spec". I was expanding on Temani's answer by highlighting that the notes in the W3C editor's draft spec I mentioned state this is an unresolved issue - suggesting this may change in a future specification.

Additional note that this currently also applies to the zero specificity selector :where().